# How to reliably detect disk is down on Linux via Java

Tags: java, linux, disk, mount

Is there a good way to detect that particular disk went offline on server on Linux, via Java?

I have an application, that due to performance reasons, writes to all disks directly (without any RAID in middle).

I need to detect if Linux would unmount any disk due to disk crash during run-time, so I would stop using it. The problem is that each mount has a root directory, so without proper detection, the application will just fill-up the root partition.

Will appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this so there might be a better way, but one option would be to run commands like mount directly from Java and read the output. See:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: If it's for linux only, you can read and parse [/proc/mounts](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) and check for that directory there.

Comment: Just as an aside, remember that your OS (with or without a RAID controller) can do amazing things to optimize IO (caching, delayed writing, read ahead, ...) so be carefull when bypassing it to gain performances ...

Comment: I'm actually using standard Java calls, so no OS bypassing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, everything is accessible through text files. I don't really understand what is the exact information you require, but check `/proc/diskstat`, `/proc/mounts`, `/proc/mdstat` (for raids), etc...

Comment: @Guillaume Well, pretty amazing is obviously not enough for the OP. He is trying to do a micro optimization (several percent tops), why not use raw system calls and C then?

Comment: @SyBer u can also use df command to know disk space occupied.

Comment: @Guillaume Actually I was talking more about direct system calls (although I guess you can do that in Java as well) not language vs. language.

Comment: I'm using pure Java to write to disks, which indeed as Guillaume said, improved significantly and provides very descent performance. The reason of why I'm bringing the speed, is because there are no HW raid planned for the target machines (due to several reasons), and from our benchmarks, the software raid is pretty slow for heavy duty writing. Hence we coding our way around by spreading data over several disks, and it works quite fine, just need this bit of detection working.

Answer (score 1):

As anyone with sysadmin experience could tell you, disks crashing or otherwise going away has a nasty habit of making any process that touches anything under the mountpoint wait in uninterruptible sleep. Additionally, in my experience, this can include things like trying to read /proc/mounts, or running the 'df' command.

My recommendation would be to use RAID, and if necessary, invest your way out of the problem. Say, if performance is limited by small random writes, a RAID card with a battery backed write cache can do wonders.

Comment: Thanks for advice, unfortunately not using RAID was one of "strategic" decisions taken early in development :).